# Flex how to get data from services inside methods

Tags: php, sql, apache-flex, dataservice

So my problem here is that i get all the data from the database using php services. the count service and the getAllData works just fine when using them on components but when i try to use them in functions i dont get anything. It's realy bugging me and i know that it something simple but i cant find a solution.

Working:

```
<s:Label id="testlabel" x="162" y="67" text="{getAllMarkersResult.lastResult[1].name}"/>
```

Not Working:

```
public function test():void
        {
            testlabel.text=getAllMarkersResult.lastResult[1].name;
        }
```

Any help? thanx

Comment: what is the datatype of the returned data? are you sure you're calling test after a request has been made?

Comment: the getallmarkersresult returns a Markers[] array containing all the info from the database. the strange thing is that when i use it in a component it works properly. for the first example i get the name of the second line in the database. when i use it in a function i get in the debug process "lastResult is undefined"

Comment: my guess would be that the binding code and your `test()` run at different times; in one case - you have a result available, in the other - you don't; what is `getAllMarkersResult` and how does it get into the mxml?

Comment: getallmarkers is an autogenerated php file for dataservices from flash builder 4.6(flex 4.6). It is used to provide some basic php functions to get data from the database.in order to use it i have to use a callservice which uses getallmarkersresult for service purposes

Comment: Yes, the binding code will run every time lastResult changes, whereas test only runs when you happen to call it.

Comment: but thats the thing when i call the test method the label gets either empty or i get an error because it says the lastResult is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that in order to use the lastresult or any other service i had to run them straight away when the view was starting and not in another function. So i created a onCreate() function initialising evarything and then called it on th xlmns: oncompletecreate:onCreate(); and everything worked like a charm.